# Where can I find exploit code?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, appsec, exploit, cve

I am doing VA/PT on a sample web application. I run the Nessus scanner and I found some high severity vulnerabilities that are related to HP System Management Homepage. The CVE-numbers are:

- CVE-2010-1917
- CVE-2010-2531
- CVE-2010-2939
- CVE-2010-2950
- CVE-2010-3709
- CVE-2010-2950
- CVE-2010-4156
- CVE-2011-1540
- CVE-2011-1541

I am trying to find exploits and tutorials to exploit these vulnerabilities. I searched on exploit-db.com, http://www.securityfocus.com and http://web.nvd.nist.gov.

I am getting the vulnerability details but unable to find the exploits. I found exploit code for CVE-2010-3709 on exploit-db.com but unable to understand how to use it?

1. Can anybody please tell me the sites where I can get exploits for these?
2. If anyone can explain me how to exploit those vulnerabilities, I will be very thankful to him.

Comment: If you have to ask "how" to exploit something then you have no business trying to exploit it.

Comment: do you know of the many commercial exploit kits out there that may have what you are looking for (including source code) or are you only looking for free resources?

Comment: I am looking for only free resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the 2010-3749 issue, presuming you're looking at [this exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/15431/) it doesn't really look like a canned exploit, more like an explanation of the issue. It would require for the application in question to make use of the vulnerable function for it to be exploitable.

Indeed, having a quick look through some of the issues that you've linked they look to be PHP language level issues. With this kind of problem, unless the codebase on the target system makes use of the vulnerable functionality, it may well not be exploitable. It could well be that Nessus is reporting vulnerability based on a received HTTP header which indicates an old version of PHP in use.

This doesn't necessarily mean that that the system in question is actually vulnerable

In addition to the sites you've mentioned I tend to look at cvedetails.com for any metasploit modules which may target the affected issue.

you could also try secunia.com and search for issues based on the product, as opposed to looking at language level issues.

Answer (score 0):

Metasploit has a massive library of actual exploit code.

http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Introduction