# Exploit database for NVD vulnerabilities

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, cve, vulnerability-management

I have the list of vulnerabilities (CVEs) in the NVD database. I need to find which one has an exploit. Is there any database available to get the list of all the exploits for CVEs? or is there any API to get them?

Comment: Please search "Exploit DB database" on the search engine. You would arrive at the right destination. Enjoy.

Comment: You can also search the same CVE in cvedetails.com and check the number of exploits available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find exploit code?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9440/where-can-i-find-exploit-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few sources I search for exploits (by CVE):

1. [Exploit Database](https://www.exploit-db.com/)
2. [CX Security](https://cxsecurity.com/exploit/)
3. [Vulnerability & Exploit Database](https://www.rapid7.com/db)
4. [0day.today](https://0day.today) (accessible via tor onion service)
5. [VulDB](https://vuldb.com/) (not exactly for exploits, but helpful)

Do check this list for [additional sources of vulnerability databases](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-pentest#vulnerability-databases)